# Hot partition problem in DynamoDB gone with the new on-demand feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I read the following announcement with great interest.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/announcing-amazon-dynamodb-on-demand/

The new "on-demand" feature really helps with capacity planning. Reading the documentation, I can't really see if they do some "magic" to resolve the problem of hot partitions, and partition key distribution.

Is partition key design just as important if you provision a table "on-demand"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, partition key design is just as important. That aspect has not changed.

Since you mentioned adaptive capacity in a comment, one thing to make sure is clear. Once it is on for a table, it is on and DynamoDB is monitoring your table.

Comment: What you say about adaptive capacity being permanent is very interesting. Can you add a link, or a source for that for further reference? I'm also curious on how that is implemented...

Answer (score 5):

There are two features at play here:
* On-demand capacity mode
* Adaptive capacity

**On-demand capacity** mode allows you to pay per each request to DynamoDB instead of provisioning a particular amount of RCUs/WCUs (this is called provisioned capacity). The benefit is that you only pay for what you use (and not for what you provision), but the downside is that if you receive a constant flow of requests, you would end up paying more if you provisioned the right amount of RCUs/WCUs. The on-demand capacity mode is the best suit for spiky traffic, while the provisioned mode is better for applications with a constant, predictable stream of requests

**Adaptive capacity** is a different feature, and it can work with either on-demand or provisioned capacity modes. It allows to "borrow" unused capacity from other partitions if one of your partitions receive a higher share of requests. It used to take some time to enable adaptive capacity, but as for now, adaptive capacity is enabled immediately.

Even with adaptive capacity, a good key design is still important. It only helps with cases when it is hard to achieve a balanced distribution of requests among shards. A single partition in DynamoDB can only handle up to 3K RCUs and 1K WCUs. So if a single partition receives more than that even with adaptive capacity requests will be throttled. So you have to design your keys to avoid this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

As of 5/2019 the answer to this question has changed.  I'd like to preface my answer by saying I have not validated this against a production workload.  Also my answer assumes you, like the OP, are using [on-demand pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/on-demand/).

First a general understanding of how DynamoDB (DDB) adaptive capacity works can be gleamed by reading [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/). Adaptive capacity is [on by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-partitions-adaptive).  In short, when a hot partition exceeds its throughput capacity, DDB "moves the rudder" and instantly increases throughput capacity on the partition.

Before 5/2019 you'd 300 seconds of instant [burst capacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-design.html#bp-partition-key-throughput-bursting), then you'd be throttled until adaptive capacity fully ["kicked in" (5-30 minutes)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/).

On 5/23/2019 AWS announced that adaptive capacity is [now instant](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-is-now-instant/).  This means no more 5-30 minute wait.

Does this mean if you use DDB on-demand pricing, your hot partition problems go away? Yes and no.

Yes, in that you should not get throttled.

No, in that your bank account will take the hit.  In order to not get throttled, DDB will scale up on-demand (now instantly).  You will pay for the RCUs and WCUs needed to handle the throughput.

So the moral is, you still have to think about hot partitions and design your application to avoid them as much as possible.  You won't be paying for it in downtime/unhappy customers, you'll be paying for it out of profits.

Comment: This answer mixed up Adaptive capacity with On demand provisioning. Please refer to next answer.

Answer (score 0):

@Glenn First of all thankyou for the great question, after some research i have reached to the conclution that hot partition problem is still important but only for 5-30 minutes as soon as dynamo db will detect you are having hot partitions it will use the mechanism like adaptive capacity and automatic resharding, dynamo db has improved a lot since its launch and now AWS handles hot partitions by something called automatic resharding, i think automatic resharding works in both on demand and provision model but i could not find any proof for that i will update the answer as soon as i find it for reference you can watch this keynote.

[AWS reinvent 2018 keynote](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=femopq3JWJg)

Comment: I've done more research: This is a very relevant and thorough article from August this year; https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-accommodates-uneven-data-access-patterns-or-why-what-you-know-about-dynamodb-might-be-outdated/ - 

A table with poorly distributed partition keys will be okay in the beginning, due to a 5-minute "Burst" reserve. After that, calls will be throttled. Adaptive Capacity will kick in after 5-30 minutes, for the hot partition - as long as table-level throughput is not exceeded.

Key distributions are still relevant it seems,,,.

Comment: NIce finding what about automatic re sharding after how much time it kicks in

Comment: Please help me understand this. If I always use on-demand capacity mode, throttling should never happen right? Does this mean hot partitions will never be an issue?

Comment: It will be an issue for 5-30 minutes but then dynamo db will repartition your key, until it all become atomic (single key) which can't be further repartitioned

Comment: This is no longer an issue.  The 5-30min wait is gone as of 5/2019 per https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/amazon-dynamodb-adaptive-capacity-is-now-instant/